# Is there any way other than .gitignore for excluding a file from getting tracked in Git?

Tags: git, gitignore

Is there any way other than .gitignore for excluding a file from getting tracked in Git?

Comment: What's wrong with adding `*.copydat` to `.gitignore`? This should be the way to go...

Comment: .copyarea files seem counterpart of .git files. They are clearcase specific. Not required in Git world.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

One way to import your ClearCase web view LATEST version (which [includes .copyxx files](http://www-01.ibm.com/support/docview.wss?uid=swg21119280)) in a git repo is to do a:

```
git init gitrepo
cd gitrepo

echo *.copydat >> .gitignore
echo *.copyarea.dat >> .gitignore
echo *.copyarea.db >> .gitignore

git --work-tree=/path/to/CC/view add .
git commit -m "Import from ClearCase view"
```

Since those files are "not required in Git world", `.gitignore` remains the right solution.

Answer (score 0):

The easiest way is adding your files to `.gitignore`. Also from [gitignore](http://but.com/docs/gitignore) documentation:

There are some additional ways to ignore files, but `.gitignore` will be the best for your case.